# WKWebView is blank when loading a Paypal captcha

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, paypal, ios14

A user can pay with Paypal inside our application.
We open the Paypal link inside a WKWebView.

But this is the result after the Paypal log-in.

[image]

When I inspect the WKWebView I find these 2 errors in the console:

```
Refused to load https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/enterprise/... because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.

Failed https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/enterprise/... to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I did not find anything on the internet to how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We open the Paypal link inside a WKWebView.

You cannot do this. From [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications)

> **Do not use a WebView to display PayPal web pages within your
> application**
>
> Your application must not use a WebView or similar custom browser
> mechanism for display of PayPal web pages. Instead, use an appropriate
> PayPal SDK to manage the PayPal experience or launch the PayPal web
> page within the system browser or an approved browser-view mechanism
> such as Safari View Controller on iOS or Chrome Custom Tabs on
> Android.

--

If your own checkout/payment flow is happening in a webview (rather than native) and you need to open a PayPal checkout from there, consider using [a popup bridge](https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios) (iOS or android version) which will convert any web popup to open in an SFVC/CCT